# How do I add a base url to a folder inside my src using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, base-url

I'm making a typescript project and and I want to set the base url so that I can do imports with paths that are relative to the src folder. My folder structure is as follows

```
src
-client
--index.html
--application.ts
-server
-shared
tsconfig
```

When I try to use the base url in my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="game-canvas"></canvas>
    <p>Client</p>
    <script src="~/client/ts/index.ts"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And run the following script

```
"watch-client": "parcel ./src/client/index.html --open --out-dir ./builds/development/public",
```

It will throw the following error

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'D:\Game\src\client\client\ts\index.ts'

it has client multiple times, why is this happening? It's almost as if it looks from the ./ that my script is compiling it from and that would be the client folder. So this would be no problem because I could just do ../ to get to my shared folder thus I changed the script in the index.html to ~/ts/index.ts and it works. But the index.ts imports an application in the same way and this works when I run the compiled build in the browser. So it's working. But now vscode throws the following error.

[image]

because vscode somehow thinks that it needs to be ~/client/ts/application.

[image]

But that throws an error in the command prompt when running the script. So how can I solve this error in vscode? The best thing would be if the path's can be relative to my src folder, but honestly, I wouldn't know how I could get that to work. This is what the parcel docs say

https://parceljs.org/typeScript.html#baseurl-and-paths

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
      "compilerOptions": {
        /* Basic Options */
        "target": "ES6",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
        "lib": ["DOM", "ES2018"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        "allowJs": false,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
        "checkJs": false,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
        "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
        "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
        //"noEmit": false,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
        "declaration": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
          "~*": ["./*"]
        },

        /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
        "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
        "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
        "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
        "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
        "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

        /* Additional Checks */
        "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
        "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
        "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

        /* Module Resolution Options */
        "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
        "experimentalDecorators": true
      },
      "include": ["src/**/*"],
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `tsconfig.json` located in your folder structure?

Comment: Same level as the src